# concatenate/append a string to a list of numbers in a text file

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with my code. I have a list with numbers like this:

```
1
4
6
9
...
```

How can I add a string to get a result like this:

```
node_1
node_4
node_6
node_9
...
```

Here is my code:

```
import random  
#creamos una lista con un primer número aleatorio  
lista=[random.randrange(19683)+1] #el primer número nunca se repite  
n=1 #n indica la cantidad de números en la lista  
while n<377:  
 x=random.randrange(19683)+1  
 norepe=True #suponemos inicialmente que el número generado no está repetido  
 while norepe:  
  for j in range(len(lista)):  
   if x==lista[j]:  
    norepe=False #aquí hemos detectado que el número si esta repetido  
  if norepe:  
   lista.append(x)  
   n+=1  

list1=sorted(lista)
print(list1)
#################################
itemlist='nodos'
with open("selectos3.txt",'w') as lista2:
     lista2.write('\n'.join(map(str,list1)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate the list then concatenate it with fixed string 'node_' and add in the new list.

```
list1=sorted(lista)
new_list = []
for lst in list1:
    strr = "node_"+str(lst)
    print (strr)
    new_list.append(strr)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
s = 'node_'
l = [1, 4, 6, 9]
result = ['node_' + i for i in map(str, l)]

print(*result, sep='\n')
```

output:

```
node_1
node_4
node_6
node_9
```